# How to remove sign_up path from devise retaining change password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

I want to remove the default sign up path or just **route the sign_up path to sign_in**. Is it possible to do so? I want to retain the change password option. so removing registerable on model is not a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use devise_scope for the same. In your routes.rb file define a scope like following before devise_for.

devise_scope :user do
    get "users/sign_up", :to => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :sign_up
end

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But now there is a new problem. All the default  routes related to password has changed. I have applied those changes but now after submitting forgot password page, its not getting redirected to root page.